# Reverse proxy same naked domain to different hosts

Tags: heroku, dns, reverse-proxy, cloudflare, netlify

I'm managing the DNS of my domain with Cloudflare.

The marketing pages for are hosted with Netlify.

The main application is hosted with Heroku.

Is it possible with cloudflare + a naked domain (my-example.com) to have some paths being served by Netlify and other paths by Heroku?

Or am I forced to put one of the hosting services on a subdomain?

Comment: [This](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/206190798-Using-Resolve-Override-in-Page-Rules) might help

Comment: @DusanBajic Hm, $200+ per month... :/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Disclaimer:  I work for Netlify.

You can definitely do this without running your own server or paying anything extra.

Since Netlify already has a CDN, it's suboptimal to put [cloudflare's CDN (activated with the 'orange cloud' in their settings)](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/when-to-orange-cloud-a-record/3636) in front of Netlify's.  Besides being inefficient, doing so breaks Netlify's [atomic deploys and rollbacks](https://www.netlify.com/docs/versioning-and-rollbacks/) and also slows down page service from our observations.  It may work, but is not recommended.  However, CloudFlare's DNS is quite performant and can be used without their CDN (turn off the 'orange cloud').  Their DNS works well with content hosted on Netlify's CDN.

Here's how to set things up to accomplish this via Netlify.

1. Deploy your static assets to a Netlify site at your main custom domain, let's say it's my-example.com.  For testing purposes you can use the built-in sitename at Netlify (something-something-1234.netlify.com) instead of my-example.com.  The below example redirects are "host agnostic" so will work with the Netlify hostname, [Netlify deploy previews](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2016/07/20/introducing-deploy-previews-in-netlify/),  AND the production hostname.
2. Find all the paths for your dynamic content - for this example, let's say it's /main/* and /app/* that are dynamic and your backend is hosted on Heroku.
3. Create [proxy redirect rules](https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects/#proxying) to point to those paths.  They could be hosted via CloudFlare's CDN to protect your API if you wanted to - Netlify proxying to CloudFlare-fronted sites on Heroku works fine.  You could also choose just to proxy straight to Heroku which would be less complicated.  Netlify has some DDoS protection built-in and is still "in front of" your Heroku app.  Up to you.
4. Deploy those proxy rules and test.

Netlify's proxying (technically reverse proxying) can connect to whatever backend you'd like and does NOT show the URL to the visitor - it looks to them (URL bar in the browser, HTTPS connection) as though they are connected to my-example.com the whole time, but the content is returned from your backend (including HTTP status codes.  This response is cached on Netlify's CDN if indicated by your `Cache-Control:` HTTP Header directives which the Heroku app sends.  Note that CloudFlare **WILL CHANGE** your Cache-Control header in case you set it on content they proxy to!  Netlify won't.)

Here's a common setup:

`/main/* https://yourapp.herokuapp.com/main/:splat 200!
 /app/* https://yourapp.herokuapp.com/main/:splat 200!`

Note that if you deploy ANY assets under /main or /app to Netlify, they will be ignored due to the trailing `!` on those rules.  See https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects/#note-on-shadowing for some more details about how that works and the alternatives (TL;DR: deploying some things like /main/logo.png on Netlify but nothing that Heroku should serve vs deploying ALL needed content for /main/* on Heroku).

Note that I suggest using identical paths on Netlify and Heroku (`/main/*`) rather than proxying to `/somethingelse/*` since it is easier to debug asset loading when paths match up.  This isn't a requirement, though.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, its possible using cloudflare enterprise service.

But you can do it with a simple nginx reverse proxy setup.

Have DNS resolve to nginx reverse proxy and based on the path, appropriately call the upstreams.

```
eg. example.com, and then direct queries for /path1 to 100.100.100.100 and for /path2 to 200.200.200.200
```