# Netlify - Multiple apps under a single custom domain aka routing

Tags: netlify

I am using netlify and would like to build 2 apps, which basically create static `/dist` folders.

Now I would like netlify to manage routing for example `app.com/app1` and `app.com/app2` to point to the two various builds.

Is this possible via the `.toml` file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've already answered a question about an identical use case here:  [Reverse proxy same naked domain to different hosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51091788/reverse-proxy-same-naked-domain-to-different-hosts/51108863#51108863)

While that answer refers to cloudflare because the question did, the answer is how to do it using just Netlify.  I use the `_redirects` syntax in the answer instead, but the workflow is the same:

1. deploy two Netlify sites to make two builds.  One will be app.com and one will be your subsite.  The multiple build commands, you will only be able to control with two toml files **assuming that you have two repos**.  If they are subdirs in the same repo, the config will have to be in netlify's UI (also possible via API) instead.
2. [(reverse) proxy](https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects/#proxying) from the main site to the subsite for the subdirectory
3. using toml syntax like the below on the main site (app.com):

   ```
   [[redirects]]
     from = "/subsite/*"
     to = "https://other-netlify-site.netlify.com/subsite/:splat"
     status = 200
     force = true
   ```

Comment: Not sure if this works if I have a single domain. Because I need to deploy two apps at various paths or subdomains.

Comment: ah.  my example is for "I'd like to serve two sites at one hostname" but you can just set up two separate sites for two separate subdomains.  Or apply 2 subdomains to the same site using [a domain alias](https://www.netlify.com/docs/custom-domains/#domain-aliases) for the second one, and use the [hostname-specific redirects](https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects/#handling-hostnames-and-protocols-differently)

Comment: Trying to understand this answer: suppose I have site1 deployed at something-something-1234.netlify.com, and site2 deployed at something-something-5678.netlify.com. How can I set things up so that when a user visits my domain example.com/site1/foo, they see the same content as at something-something-1234.netlify.com/foo, and when they visit example.com/site2/bar, they see the same content as at something-something-5678.netlify.com/bar (with the url always saying example.com, never netlify.com)? I'm not even sure if this is the same question that's asked here — should I ask a new one? Thanks!

Comment: Ah I found this, which helped me understand better: [“When you assign an HTTP status code of 200 to a redirect rule, it becomes a rewrite. This means that the URL in the visitor’s address bar remains the same, while Netlify’s servers fetch the new location behind the scenes.”](https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects/#rewrites-and-proxying) — I guess this usage of the term “redirect” was non-obvious to me and could stand being pointed out explicitly, but after reading that it's now clearer.

Comment: Further caveat (deleted earlier comment saying it doesn't work): It appears the above kind of redirect only works if https is set up properly (e.g. won't work if you've newly started using a domain with Netlify and it's still waiting for DNS propagation to complete); until then you get a 301 redirect. This makes sense in hindsight, but maybe this could be mentioned under “limitations” in the [rewrites](https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects/#rewrites-and-proxying) section.